# How do I add a partition (specifically swap) to my raid0 laptop setup?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, raid, acer

EDIT: yes, gparted was the (in hindsight obvious) answer

I foolishly didn't create swap space when I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on my Acer laptop with 2 SSDs preconfigured as raid0. Now I regret that and I'm totally lost trying to re-understand my partitioning. The output of lsblk is even less intelligible than I remembered:

```
~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk   
└─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume    252:0    0   477G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume1 252:2    0   600M  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume2 252:3    0   300M  0 part   /boot/efi
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume3 252:4    0   128M  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume4 252:5    0  77.1G  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume5 252:6    0    16G  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume6 252:7    0    29G  0 part   /
  └─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume7 252:8    0 265.4G  0 part   /home
sdb                         8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk   
└─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume    252:0    0   477G  0 dmraid 
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume1 252:2    0   600M  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume2 252:3    0   300M  0 part   /boot/efi
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume3 252:4    0   128M  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume4 252:5    0  77.1G  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume5 252:6    0    16G  0 part   
  ├─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume6 252:7    0    29G  0 part   /
  └─isw_iebbijfhi_Volume7 252:8    0 265.4G  0 part   /home
```

iirc the system came to me with the first five subvolumes and I added the partitions for root and home. Only sda and sdb exist in /dev and mdadm won't detail them for me because they don't appear to be md devices.

What is the appropriate tool or set of tools to get a clear picture of my partitions and edit them, preferably without wiping everything?

Secondary question: Would it be smarter to just make a swap file and not mess with my already messing partitioning? Secondary because I want to understand the system more than I actually want to solve my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: try [gparted](http://gparted.org/download.php) 'sudo apt-get install gparted'. You can delete some of the partition or shrink some partition/volume to create space for swap.